# Self adjoint operator whose spectrum contains a single point

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $S$ be a self-adjoint operator on  Hilbert space. Suppose that $\sigma(S) = \{\lambda\}$. Show that $S = \lambda I$.

I'm not sure at all how to approach this question.

I've tried a couple of  things:

We have that either $S-\lambda I$ is not injective, in which case there exists an $x\in H$ such that $Sx = \lambda x$, but I don't know how to conclude that this is the case for all $x\in H$, or $S-\lambda I$ is not surjective, but I don't know what to do with that.

I know that $\|S\|$ or $-\|S\|$ must be in $\sigma(S)$, so I know that $\|S\| = |\lambda|$, and also that $\lambda$ is real.

Also, since $\|S\| =\sup\{\langle Sx, x\rangle : \|x\| = 1\}$, I have that $\langle Sx, x\rangle \leq |\lambda|$ for all $x$ with $\|x\| = 1$, but again I don't know where to go from there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** instead of considering $S$, consider $S-\lambda I$, which has spectrum $\{0\}$.

Comment: Since $\pm \|S-\lambda I\|$ is in the spectrum, we have $\|S-\lambda I\| = 0$ which implies that $S = \lambda I$. Very simple. Thankyou